# Meaning of недоперепить

Tags: глаголы

Искал этот глагол в нескольких словарях, но не тут-то было.

> в этот раз **недоперепил**, так что нормально.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Недоперепить" is a very colloquial, non-standard verb. It's no surprise you haven't found it in dictionaries. Still, it's used.

It means a very strange thing, I think. "Перепить" means to drink too much, with all the consequences that come with it (by that I mean a bad hangover).

The prefix "недо" is meant to negate the prefix "пере" in "пить." The result is that the whole verb means to drink a lot, but less than one would actually like to. If one says "недоперепил," it doesn't necessarily mean the person doesn't have a hangover, though.

Comment: Я все понял! Спасибо за разъяснение)))

Comment: @CocoPop спасибо и Вам за интересный вопрос!

Answer (score 2):

This is a facetious verb which formally doesn't exist because both prefixes negate each other.

[недоперепить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

> выпить больше, чем возможно, но меньше, чем хочется
>   (seems to be a classic definition)

Basically the implied idea is that overdrinking is good and you haven't had enough of it.

Comment: Для меня "выпить больше, чем возможно" не имеет никакого смысла. Именно сколько считается "возможно"? Выпить ведь можно до того, как бухло из ушей идет  Но я уловил суть))) Спасибо!

Comment: @CocoPop not my definition though, i'm just the messenger, i might rephrase it as ***больше чем можно было бы*** or ***больше, чем нужно***

Comment: Уровень _перепития_ относителен :) . Если обозначать словом **недоперепил** недостигнутый желанный уровень, то можно вспомнить, что говорят в шутку о степенях перепития ирландцы: "ирландец пьёт не до опьянения, а до протрезвления".